# How to not display logs in Xcode output, but still send them to Hockeyapp reports

Tags: ios, hockeyapp, cocoalumberjack

I am using Hockeyapp for crash reporting and collecting logs when the app crashes. Using the method below.

```
- (void)setupLumberjack {
    // Configure CocoaLumberjack
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

    // Initialize File Logger
    // initialize before HockeySDK, so the delegate can access the file logger!
    _fileLogger = [[DDFileLogger alloc] init];
    _fileLogger.maximumFileSize = (1024 * 128); // 128 KByte
    _fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 5;
    [_fileLogger rollLogFileWithCompletionBlock:nil];
    [DDLog addLogger:_fileLogger];
}
```

Setting the log level:

`static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_ALL;`

Now I would like to get ALL log levels still sent to Hockeyapp reports, but surpress ANY output in the xcode console.

How can I achieve that? Probably missing something here.

Using version 1.9.2 but willing to update to 2.x if that would be necessary.

Comment: Have you tried just not adding `DDTTYLogger`? Sounds like that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Xcode logs are always displayed in the Xcode console.
You don't have any way to disable them.

But you can hide the output window :P

You also can set a Custom Compiler Flags for your Debug build settings.

[image]

Then you code a `DLog()` macro that will echo `NSLog()` only if this flag is there => only when debugging with Xcode.
With this the users won't have any log on their device.

Comment: Lol :)

Ok, let me rephrase that. I don't want that all my precious logs are visible to others using the Xcode->Devices->Device Console.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for was posted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411235/how-to-not-display-logs-in-xcode-output-but-still-send-them-to-hockeyapp-report?noredirect=1#comment62329961_37411235).

Simply removing this line did the trick:
`[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];`